# ActivityResultLauncher always returns null data

Tags: android-intent, androidx, android-pendingintent, registerforactivityresult, activity-result-api

i'm using `ActivityResultLauncher` with `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult` contract in android 11 to modify audio files.

Here's how i'm doing it in my `MainActivity`:

1. i use `MediaStore` to create a write request which returns a `PendingIntent`, then i call `#getIntentSender()`, to get an `IntentSender`:

   `IntentSender sender = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(getContentResolver(), uris).getIntentSender();`
2. then i create an `IntentSenderRequest` and i set it's fillIn `Intent` like below:

   `Intent fillIn = new Intent().putExtras(bundle);`

   `IntentSenderRequest senderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender).setFillInIntent(fillIn).build();`
3. then i call my launcher like below:

   `myLauncher.launch(senderRequest);`

and my result launcher is like this:

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> myLauncher = 
registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                //result.getData() is always null
            }
```

but every time i call `myLauncher`, data is null

i'm using androidx version 1.4.1

Comment: have you solved this? I have same problem.

Comment: @khushbuvadi I solved it in a different way, i created an interface called ResultHandler which acts like a bundle and has a method which handles the result from ActivityResultLauncher